# UINavigationBar Bottom hairline returns after UISearchBarDelegate is canceled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I've got a UINavigationBar on top of a UISearchBar that I want to blend together as one seamless piece.  Using this alone does not work:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

but with this:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBackground"]
                   forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
navBarHairlineImageView = [self findHairlineImageViewUnder:navigationBar];
```

I can find and remove the right subview and problem solved.  However, when I activate the search, and cancel the search, the hairline is reset.  Is this a new view? How do I ensure that the hairline stays invisible after search is canceled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
        [subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]];
        subView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

remember to set it to NO when you transfer to other viewController

Comment: Where would you do this, in the view controller's searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch?

Comment: in the viewController's `viewWillAppear` set hidden = YES and in `viewWillDisappear` set hidden = NO